# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Profiler is not defined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm having this error , the swf compiled with flex builder

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Profiler is not defined.
at global$init()
at core::Emulator()[C:\Users\AJ\Documents\Flex Builder 3\Snes\src\core\Emulator.as:67]
at Snes/onRomLoaded()[C:\Users\AJ\Documents\Flex Builder 3\Snes\src\Snes.as:90]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

any help would be great.

Emulator.as file : http://txtup.net/8CP6r

Snes.as file : http://txtup.net/b9WW

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: the code is here:
http://txtup.co/qojL7

Comment: It's nice that you added the code, however, that's not too helpful. The reason is that the error above says the problem is on line #67 of your `Emulator` class. But now we have to count to line 67 in the code that you linked to. I have trouble counting past 10 :) Can you look in your IDE on line 67, then edit your question and add that line? If using Flash Builder you can press CMD-L or CTRL-L and enter 67 to jump to that line. I tried searching for the variable "Profiler" in your code, but couldn't even find the word anywhere. So perhaps it's best you show us what line 67 looks like. Cheers!

Comment: this is line 67:  cLoader = new CLibInit();

Comment: Please check the post again i just posted the 2 files having the errors with line numbers.

Comment: Sorry for being silly in my comment. In my sillyness I missed the fact that line entry about line 67 in the stack trace has one more entry above it. It's referring to some code in a function called global$init() -- that function global$init() is triggered by line 67 of the Emulator class. So now the culprit seems to be the class CLibInit -- but it doesn't give a line number in that class.

Comment: I did some googling on "flex global$init()" -- it looks like that is an internal method of the Flex framework. You might find some help by doing the same search, but frankly, all the other problems people were reporting seemed different than yours. Although, one common thread was that they experienced the error after upgrading to a newer version of the Flex framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading your code, can you paste following lines and check if your "cLoader" variable is getting initialize properly? or it would be great if you can provide source for "CLibInit" class as well.

```
cLoader = new CLibInit();
if(cLoader){
  cLoader.supplyFile( "romfile", rom );                         
  cLib = cLoader.init();            
  cLib.setup();
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, Actully i tried to use if but i'm getting an error, The Clibint is a swc library, I upload it for you so with all the files to make it easy to take a look.
http://www.4shared.com/zip/ljmL5I05/source.html